# How do I select the hyphenation algorithm I want to use.

Tags: xetex, hyphenation

I'd like to use a particular hyphenation pattern, not linked to the language I defined as main language (with polyglossia in xelatex).

Is there something like this:?

```
\selecthyphenation{french}
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, you don't want to change the algorithm, but only the patterns (used as data in the algorithm), so the title of your question is a bit misleading...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you would likely use:

```
 \usepackage{polyglossia}
 \setdefaultlanguage{english}
 \setotherlanguage{french}
```

in the header, and then:

```
 \begin{french}

 <Text here>

 \end{french}
```

...in the body for a paragraph in a non-default language. 
See page 5 of the [polyglossia](http://ctan.org/pkg/polyglossia) package documentation.